# Efficient data structure and/or algorithm for searching if a word is in a set of words?

Tags: python, algorithm, hash

Suppose I have a set of words. For any given word, I would like to find if it is already in the set. What is some efficient data structure and/or algorithm for implementing that?

1. For example, is the following way using a hash table a good way?

   - first store the set of words, by using some hash function and a hash table.
   - given a query word, calculate its hash value and see if it is in the hash table.
2. In Python, is there already some data structure and/or algorithm
   which can be used to implement the way you recommend?

Thanks!

Comment: Python has dictionaries...

Comment: Python has sets, too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python has sets.  For example:

```
>>> foo = set()
>>> foo.add('word')
>>> 'word' in foo
True
>>> 'bar' in foo
False
```

Comment: is set more efficient than hashing?

Comment: The set implementation in Python uses a hash.  It is all being done for you by Python. At least the cpython implementation uses hashing.

Comment: in python, both set and dictionary are implemented using hash tables. So which one is more efficient?

Comment: A set is a dictionary without any values stored with the keys.  Use a set if you don't have data to store with the key.

Comment: thanks. Does finding if a word is in a set of words belong to the "search algorithm"

Comment: Certainly determining if a word is in a set is a search.

Answer (score 2):

```
mywords = set(["this", "is", "a", "test"])

"test" in mywords       # => True
"snorkle" in mywords    # => False
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, python has a native dictionary data structure that is implemented using a HashTable, and so the in operator is executed in O(1) time on dictionaries. Per Allen Downey in [Think Python](http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/thinkpython.html)

> The in operator uses different algorithms for lists and dictionaries.
>   For lists, it uses a search algorithm, as in Section 8.6. As the list
>   gets longer, the search time gets longer in direct proportion. For
>   dictionaries, Python uses an algorithm called a hashtable that has a
>   re- markable property: the in operator takes about the same amount of
>   time no matter how many items there are in a dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, if you're building a large set of words overtime and the words aren't too long consider using trie.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyTrie